# Flow publisher to string in java9

Tags: java, rx-java

How can I get a string from `Flow.Publisher<Byte> body`? 
I just want to parse the string from Publisher.

Comment: Did you try writing any code yet?  There are at least two easy ways to aggregate bytes: [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how you can do it with [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava):

```
Flow.Publisher<Byte> bytes = ...;

Flowable.fromPublisher(
        FlowAdapters.toPublisher(
            bytes
        )
    ).toList()
        .map(byteList -> new String(convert(byteList)))
        .subscribe((String string) -> {
            System.out.println(string);
        });
```

convert is defined as following:

```
   static byte[] convert(List<Byte> list) {
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[list.size()];
        int idx = 0;
        for (byte b : list) {
            bytes[idx] = b;
            idx++;
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is better to use one of the established reactive library instead of
working with `Flow.Publisher`s directly.

In general, you can collect up the bytes and when the sequence completes, then turn it into a String:

```java
Flow.Publisher<Byte> bytes = ...

bytes.subscribe(new Flow.Subscriber<Byte>() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription s) {
        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Byte t) {
        bout.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        try {
            System.out.println(bout.toString("UTF-8"));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would say it is a good approach in general. But to use RxJava2 for that makes the task fairly simple

Comment: It wasn't clear if the OP wanted a native Flow.Publisher solution or wanted to work with RxJava. Many slap the `rx-java` tag on questions if it somehow relates to reactive.